# In the client, Is there a way to get the html of a webpage without getting any additional html that has been injected after load eg chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that lets you enable `designMode` to make changes to any websites text. Once the user is ready I want to be able to save the HTML from the webpage.

I've tried to use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to get the HTML but it would also grab injected dom elements from chrome extensions that I have installed, I would like to still get the html without turning chrome extensions off as I need them.

Is there a way to get the page's HTML but not get any additional code such as chrome extensions.